# A computer program generates random strings consisting of five letters.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A computer program generates random strings consisting of five letters, which are chosen from any of the following seven: a, g, j, o, x, y, z, with repetitions allowed. Answer the following:

a) How many different strings are possible?

b) How many different strings are there that contain two or more identical letters?

c) What is the probability of a string having no letter ‘a’ and containing two or more identical letters?

a) $7^5 = 16807$

b) $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = 2520$

$16807 - 2520 = 14287$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I don't understand the things you wrote starting from $x = $ number from 1-8

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: For (c), do the analogous computations you did for (a) and (b) but for 6 letters instead of 7, and divide that by your answer to (a).

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.   Your answers to the first two questions are correct.  Apply Ned's strategy for the third question.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.